# issue with sscanf and comparing number

Tags: c, scanf

I need help. My program is starting with: ./proj --tan 1.024 6 10 I count tangens through Taylor'
s polynom. Range of iteration is 1 to 13. I need to stop program if nuber of iteration is higher then 13, but my code below don't work.

```
if ((sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &n) >= 14) || (sscanf(argv[3], "%d", &n) < 0))
    {
        return ERROR_WRONG_NUM;
    }
    if ((sscanf(argv[4], "%d", &m) >= 14) || (sscanf(argv[4], "%d", &m) < 0))
        return ERROR_WRONG_NUM;
```

Comment: `sscanf` returns the number of items that were successfully scanned, not the value that was scanned. You should call `sscanf` **once**, and then compare `if (n >= 14 || n < 0)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of `sscanf` is the number of input items assigned, or `EOF` when failed, which is not what you expected.

You should compare `n` with the range `[1,13]` after checking the return value from `sscanf`

```
items = sscanf( argv[3], "%d", &n );
if ( items != 1 || n < 1 || n > 13 ) 
    return ERROR_WRONG_NUM;
```